# Replace a text with select bootstrap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace a text `test` with a select bootstrap when I click to the text and I want do this with jquery.

Here my html :

```html
<text class="TextDb" style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;cursor:pointer">Test</text>
```

Here the select bootstrap that i want add it in the code jquery :

```html
<div class="dropdown">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Dropdown button
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Now where is that jQuery you're talking about? Have you tried anything yet? Hint: [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) is probably a good place to start

Comment: @tshimkus i'am new with jquery so i want someone help me

Comment: There are a couple ways to trigger the event. You can add an `onclick` attribute to the `<text>` tag that calls a function or you can use a jquery click handler [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/). You will probably want the click event removed after the click so you can click on the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with Bootstrap 4.3 and jQuery 3.3.1

I'm making some assumptions here but it does literally what you asked.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXGjww

```
<text class="TextDb" style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;cursor:pointer">Test</text>

<div class="dropdown d-none">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Dropdown button
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {

  $('.TextDb').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('d-none');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$("#yourdropdownid").on("change",function(e){
   $("#yourtextid").val( $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text());
})
```